# How to implement override concept in php namespaced project

Tags: php, laravel

Currently we have a project based on laravel, all our logic is situated in a separate folder in laravel called xxx, and it uses namespace A. We need to implement an override concept which will work following way.

We want to have another folder yyy on the same level with xxx, which may have exact the same file structure with xxx.

And if there is a file aaa.php where some class is implemented in xxx, if we create same file in yyy, we should be able to override the class there, add or override methods there. In order to use the same class name we need to be under some other namespace, for example B

So in config we need to specify, if we using namespace A or namespace B, and based on this the override must work or not.

PHP doesn't let you to force namespace B when inheriting a class, and because of this the non inherited functions still use namespace A.

What overriding concept can handle our needs ?

Comment: This is precisely what the `IoC` service container in laravel was built for. You can easily add an instance of your application bound to the IoC and then override it. Have a look [https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/providers).

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the info, can you bring a short example how Service provider can help in our case?

Answer (score 0):

You can use design pattern. [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-the-factory-method-design-pattern/)
[link 2](http://coderoncode.com/design-patterns/programming/php/coding/development/2014/01/19/design-patterns-php-factories.html)

Comment: This method is not good for IDE, the class references are lost forever